# Get friends profile pic url php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello friends I am trying to get friends profile pic url.

But Im getting this error.

```
Cannot use object of type Facebook\FacebookResponse as array in /home/shortbuc/public_html/facebook/callback.php on line 25
```

Below is my callback.php

```
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();  
try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
 }
$friends = $fb -> get("me/invitable_friends? fields=id,first_name,picture.type(large)", $accessToken);
$friendpic = $friends['data'][0][picture]['data'][url];
echo $friendpic;
```

How can I get friends profile pic url.

Thanks.

Comment: what for do you need a large version of the profile picture? i am not sure if it is possible to get the large version with invitable_friends. btw, there is whitespace in your api call, between "?" and "fields".

Comment: I am able to get large picture. Everything is working just unable to get a pic of one friend. need to retrive only one or may be two urls.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook usually uses JSON as response format. Looking at your code, it seems you forgot to add the second parameter to `json_decode`. Then this parameter is assumed as `false`. This means `json_decode` will decode the data to its standard format: objects. So the second parameter should be `true` to get the data as an (associative) array.

Example: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#example-4315

Comment: Please tell me in which line I have to add. I added friends to it it gives NULL response

Comment: I think, it's somewhere inside your `get` function where `json_decode` is used. I don't know what code is there. So I can't tell you, which line you have to modify. If you're using a library, you should have a look, if you can define the return type before you call the `get` function.